# how can I concatenate strings in csh file in linux?

Tags: csh

I have to concatenate string to another string (that contains an argument).

> set file="a-${var}"

I need to concatenate

> "_set.csh"

to $file.

How do i do it?

i tried the reguar way, but it just overrides and does not concatenate:

> set file="a-${var}"

> set con="_set.csh"

> set file="${file}${con}"

and the output i got:

> "_set.csh"

i'ld like to get:

> "a-12_set.csh"

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the "regular way" that you tried? BTW: I just removed the "linux" tag, which had nothing to do with your question, as you could have seen from the description as well.

Comment: Hey @Ulrich Eckhardt , I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, much better now!

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt , Can you help me please?

Comment: Sorry, can't, I have no experience with CSH.

Comment: I found the solution. the problem was the file is not Unix format. I resolved it.